# ASP. NET MVC multilingual site design

Tags: razor, multilingual

Recently I joined  a project which has a ASP.NET mvc based website supporting only English language. It needs to incorporate multilingual features now. All the multilingual texts,  fonts,  pixels etc needs to be fetched from the Database. Till here everything is fine.

Now the main requirement is to have the html cached per language from the server side(for better performance) with the multilingual texts and html attributes like fonts,  pixels applied and after that we need to fetch the actual data and bind it to the html. Is it possible using razor views? If yes can someone suggest the design approach?

Comment: How you are caching data??

Comment: That's not yet decided.For the time being we cache the html metadata in a concurrent dictionary(not using any expiration policy as of now)

Comment: based on the language id fetch the cache data from the view model.

Comment: Here it's not only html metadata caching but the requirement is to cache the razor views(basically the final html to be rendered) per language as well and that's where I am not able to find a solution.

Comment: Something similar can be done using xslt as suggested here http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/3/implementing_an_xslt_view_engine_for_asp_net_mvc but not sure how to do that using razor. By the way can xslt be used to transform an XML into cshtml razor views?

Comment: Using the xslt approach what I could do is I could serialize the html metadata view model into an xml and could use xslt to transform it into an html and then I could cache the html per language.But the project is quite big and having all htmls being rendered via cshtml razor views and thats why searching some razor based solution.

Comment: [This link](https://maxtoroq.github.io/2014/02/using-razor-and-xslt-in-same-project.html) seems helpful but is there some tool to transform cshtml to razor views since that would be easier for me to write the xslt for the existing cshtmls else myself(& my project mates) have to do things manually.

Comment: It's html data*(and not html metadata).My bad!

Comment: Don't think the custom ViewEngine Approach is going to work.First of all, along with the html attributes data the actual data is also going to get binded in the razor view which would be dynamic and so no point of caching the whole html.Also ViewEngine is going to come into action only for actions which returns ViewResult - not going to work for other ActionResult types.If I dont use the Razor views(& associated HTML Helpers), binding the data needs to be taken care in some other way(& also unobtrusive Javascript wont work by default even after using Data Annotations).

Comment: read the link provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/performance-and-traffic/15-caching-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-website, hope it help you

Comment: @VinuthaN : This is data caching and what I asked is about "html Layout" caching per language.Anyways leave it.I dont think thats possible using Razor views.